# Static Resource to background-image property

Tags: javascript, css, image, get, resources

My app retrieves images as a static resource (GET request URL), for which the links are generated dynamically per session. I'd like to take that image and use JS to set it as a background-image of a particular element.

Resource link example:

```
GET http://our.domain.com/image/get?email=mail@mail.com&authToken=blahblah
```

Then once I have the file, I'd like to do

```
document.querySelector('.avatar').style.backgroundImage = 'path/to/file'
```

What needs to happen to do this? Do I have to put the file in browser storage? I don't know where to begin with this. Please help me get on the right track. :)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nr60rjrp/4/)

Comment: is there any reason you can't just do:  `document.querySelector('.avatar').style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://our.domain.com/image/get?email=mail@mail.com&authToken=blahblah)';`

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to work. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nr60rjrp/2

Comment: it does if you use valid css - https://jsfiddle.net/nr60rjrp/3/

Comment: okay, I got the fiddle working by adding height and width and removing the outer quotes from the declaration, but for some reason I am still struggling to get it to work in the JS. I will update the question with the js.

Comment: yes, a tag with some dimensions helps with getting a background :p

Comment: I updated the question with the latest fiddle - trying to add it to the style property with JS.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nr60rjrp/7/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nr60rjrp/8/ you code edited and fixed also added in my updated anser

Comment: aha! background-size! Thanks!

Comment: yep, if you filter out all the noise around here, you can get an answer pretty easily